# Shared library on Linux and -fPIC error

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, shared-libraries, fpic

I am trying to compile a shared library in Linux using a Makefile created with Cmake, but running make I obtain the following error:

```
   Linking CXX shared library libcpp-lib.so
   /usr/bin/ld: /home/davide/Desktop/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.a(error_code.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata.str1.1 can  not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
   /home/davide/Desktop/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.a: could not read symbols:   Bad value
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   make[2]: *** [libcpp-lib.so] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp-lib.dir/all] Error 2
   make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I provide the following command in the CMakeLists.txt in order to say that I want a shared (.so) library:

`add_library(cpp-lib SHARED ${CPP_FILES})`

What else do I need to specify in order to avoid the -fPIC error shown above?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The boost libraries needs to be compiled using -fPIC:
Please have a look at: [How to compile static library with -fPIC from boost.python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418838/how-to-compile-static-library-with-fpic-from-boost-python)

Try to add compiler flags by cmake by in your project:

```
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fPIC")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")
```

Comment: I have same problem. Done that. No result.
At start I write:
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fPIC")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "$CMAKE_C_FLAGS -fPIC")`

After "add_library" I add:

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-fPIC")

No result. At all. How else to solve that? Problem goes with `libboost_system.a`.

Comment: setting  `CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` or usage of `POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` target property is better way as it is compiler independent. Also `CMAKE_*_FLAGS` manipulation is not so good as user may change it in cache file