# How to fix 'Makefile:257: recipe for target 'rugged.so' failed' (rugged)

Tags: ruby, bundler, rugged

I'm trying to install `pronto` gem and one of its dependency (rugged) is failing to build.

So, trying to run `gem install rugged` gives me such output https://pastebin.com/m6v2RgQt

I've checked that I have `cmake` installed and other optional dependencies listed here https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2#optional-dependencies.

My guesses are

1) I'm using `rbenv` and this somehow can mess with Ruby path

2) My machine configuration

Do you have any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26549137/3784008).

Comment: Please do not link to external sites that host your code. If you have code that is relevant to your question then you must include it directly in your question.